# MI bot de discord repite la salida del codigo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

Tengo un bot para discord en python3 y al ejecutar los comandos me repite siempre el resultado, por ejemplo si le digo q si escribo hola me diga adios me dice todo el tiempo adios, aqui dejo el código, como puedo solucionarlo?? muchas gracias(el token lo oculto)

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('token-oculto')
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', description="Este es el bot Sunny")
cont = 0
salida = False
cont2 = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Bot encendido')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'balon' in message.content.lower():
        global cont
        cont = cont + 1
        if(cont < 5):
            #await message.channel.send("balon: ")
            #print(cont)
            return False
        elif(cont > 5):
            print("se paso")
            cont = cont - cont
        return False
    elif 'funciona' in message.content.lower():
        global salida
        if(salida == False):
             salida = True
             await message.channel.send('FUNCIONA')
             return False
    elif 'suma' in message.content.lower():
        global cont2
        if(cont2 < 2):
            await message.channel.send(message.content.split(' '))
        else:
            cont2 = 0
        return False

client.run("token-oculto")
```

al poner suma y cualquier cosa me repite lo de sacar el array infinitas veces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El bot está reaccionando a los mensajes que está enviando el/la/le mismo/a/e bot.
Llega un mensaje -> responde -> lee su propie mensaje -> responde -> lee su ...

Para evitar que se automutile, podés hacer que no haga nada cuando es un mensaje del mismo cliente:

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

o que no reaccione al mensaje de ningún otro usuario tipo bot:

```
if message.author.bot:
    return
```